Facebook graphApi - /{pageId}/feed returning empty data array
My website uses FacebookClient to get the company's Facebook feed and display the latest posts on the site. It's no longer working (not sure how long ago it stopped). The access token expired a while ago, so I updated the access token, and the access token now works (I don't get an exception now on dynamic feedData = (IDictionary<string, object>)client.Get($"{pageId}/feed", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "limit", numResults } }); but it just returns an empty array.
I know that the pageId and accessToken are valid, because this code works:
dynamic coverImage = client.Get(pageId, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "fields","picture" }
});

but the call to get the feed returns no posts.
To make testing easier, I'm testing in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path={pageId}%2Ffeed&version=v20.0. I get the same results in the explorer. No error, just an empty data array:
{
  "data": [
  ]
}

I verified there are posts on the Facebook page as recent as 4 hours ago. If the access token and pageId are valid, why is {pageId}/feed returing no data?


Why are you using a user token, and not a page token? And what permissions does your token actually encompass, Graph API Explorer doesn't appear to show any there?

That's the setup I used before that worked. I don't know how to get a page token instead of a user token. What permissions does it need to have to see posts?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#readperms, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/#pagetokens
